# How to write a xUnit test for the method which has another method inside it?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I want to write a xUnit test for **ValidatorCreateAsync** method and here is the method:

```
public async Task<ValidationResult> ValidateCreateAsync(IJob job)
    {
        var validationResult = _validator.NullValidator(job.Payload, job.Module, job.EntityName);

        if (validationResult.ValidationResultEnum == ValidationResultEnum.Invalid)
            return validationResult;

        await _context.Jobs.InsertOneAsync(job as Job);

        return validationResult;
    }
```

Here is my NullValidator method:

```
public ValidationResult NullValidator<T>(params T[] notNullEntities)
    {
        foreach (var entity in notNullEntities)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult()
                {
                    ValidationResultEnum = ValidationResultEnum.Invalid,
                    ValidationResultMessageEnum = ValidationResultMessageEnum.NullProperty
                };
            }
        }

        return new ValidationResult()
        {
            ValidationResultEnum = ValidationResultEnum.Valid,
            ValidationResultMessageEnum = ValidationResultMessageEnum.NotNullFound
        };
    }
```

In xUnit testing, how can I write the setup for my NullValidator method to work properly on the below test ?

```
public class JobStoreTest
{

    private readonly Mock<IMongoDbContext> _moqIMongoDbContext;
    private readonly Mock<IValidator> _moqIValidator;
    private readonly JobStore _jobStore;

    public JobStoreTest()
    {
        _moqIMongoDbContext = new Mock<IMongoDbContext>();
        _moqIValidator = new Mock<IValidator>();
        _jobStore = new JobStore(_moqIMongoDbContext.Object,_moqIValidator.Object);

            _moqIMongoDbContext
            .Setup(_ => _.Jobs.InsertOneAsync(
                It.IsAny<Job>(),
                It.IsAny<InsertOneOptions>(),
                It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
            )
            .Returns((Job y, InsertOneOptions options, CancellationToken token)
                => Task.FromResult(y));

        

        //****************This code does not work here*****************
        _moqIValidator.Setup(_ => _.NullValidator(
            It.IsAny<Type[]>())
        ).Returns((Type[] y)
            => Task.FromResult(ValidationResult validation)); 

    }

    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(JobClassesForTesting))]
    public async Task CreateAsync(IJob job)
    {
        var validationResult = await _jobStore.ValidateCreateAsync(job);

        ValidationResult expectedValidationResult = new ValidationResult()
        {
            ValidationResultEnum = ValidationResultEnum.Valid,
            ValidationResultMessageEnum = ValidationResultMessageEnum.NotNullFound
        };

        Assert.Equal(expectedValidationResult, validationResult);
    }
}
```

I expect Error in the first test and others should be passed.
Here is my test scenario (JobClassesForTesting):

```
public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        

        yield return new object[]
        {
                new Job()
                {
                    Payload = null,
                    EntityName = "EntityNameTest1",
                    Module = "ModuleTest1",
                }
        };

        yield return new object[]
        {
                new Job()
                {
                    Payload = "PayloadTest2",
                    EntityName = "EntityNameTest2",
                    Module = "ModuleTest2",
                }
        };

        yield return new object[]
        {
                new Job()
                {
                    Payload = "PayloadTest3",
                    EntityName = "EntityNameTest3",
                    Module = "ModuleTest3",
                }
        };
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`job.Payload, job.Module, job.EntityName` are all string members, so `Type[]` in

```
_moqIValidator
    .Setup(_ => _.NullValidator(It.IsAny<Type[]>()))
    .Returns((Type[] y) => Task.FromResult(ValidationResult validation));
```

is the wrong type to be matched

It would require a `string[]`.

Secondly, the mocked member is not asynchronous, so does not return a `Task`. Therefore there is no reason for a callback with `Task.FromResult`

If the `IValidator` implementation used has no dependencies and no negative effects of using the actual class, then there really is no need to mock it. Use the implementation itself

For example

```
private readonly Mock<IMongoDbContext> _moqIMongoDbContext;
private readonly JobStore _jobStore;

public JobStoreTest() {
    _moqIMongoDbContext = new Mock<IMongoDbContext>();        
    _jobStore = new JobStore(_moqIMongoDbContext.Object, new Validator());

    _moqIMongoDbContext
        .Setup(_ => _.Jobs.InsertOneAsync(
            It.IsAny<Job>(),
            It.IsAny<InsertOneOptions>(),
            It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        )
        .Returns((Job y, InsertOneOptions options, CancellationToken token)
            => Task.FromResult(y));

}

//...
```

In order for all the tests to pass then the test data needs to be modified to satisfy the expectations

First update the test data to also include the expected result

```
public class JobClassesForTesting {

    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator() {
        var valid = new ValidationResult() {
            ValidationResultEnum = ValidationResultEnum.Valid,
            ValidationResultMessageEnum = ValidationResultMessageEnum.NotNullFound
        };

        var invalid = new ValidationResult() {
            ValidationResultEnum = ValidationResultEnum.Invalid,
            ValidationResultMessageEnum = ValidationResultMessageEnum.NullProperty
        };

        yield return new object[] {
            new Job() {
                Payload = null,
                EntityName = "EntityNameTest1",
                Module = "ModuleTest1",
            },
            invalid
        };

        yield return new object[] {
            new Job() {
                Payload = "PayloadTest2",
                EntityName = "EntityNameTest2",
                Module = "ModuleTest2",
            },
            valid
        };

        yield return new object[] {
            new Job() {
                Payload = "PayloadTest3",
                EntityName = "EntityNameTest3",
                Module = "ModuleTest3",
            },
            valid
        };
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

And refactor the test to take the expected result as a parameter as well for the assertion

```
[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(JobClassesForTesting))]
public async Task CreateAsync(IJob job, ValidationResult expectedValidationResult) {
    //Act
    ValidationResult validationResult = await _jobStore.ValidateCreateAsync(job);
   //Assert
   Assert.Equal(expectedValidationResult, validationResult);
}
```

Comment: _moqIValidator.Setup(_ => _.NullValidator(
                It.IsAny<string[]>())
            ).Returns((string[] y)
                => Task.FromResult(ValidationResult validation));Thanks but it doesn't work either

Comment: What does `does not work mean`? Be more specific please.

Comment: Actually I want only to see the result of ValidateCreateAsync in my test. I don't know how to.

Comment: Then use the example I showed about that uses the actual validator and not a mocked validator.

Comment: according to your answer, what should I relpace with new NullValidatorObject() ?

Comment: Initialize the actual validator class that you use you use

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to a full code ? I really appreciate that, I'm new to testing

Comment: What class does `public ValidationResult NullValidator<T>(params T[] notNullEntities)` belong to?

Comment: public class Validator : IValidator / it belongs to Validator Class

Comment: That is the object to use as validator in the test. check update

Comment: Thanks but that's not my scenario, it passes all of my tests successful, my first test in JobClassesForTesting should return NullRefrenceException.

Comment: No it wont. not according to your code. the first result would be a validation result with `new ValidationResult()
                {
                    ValidationResultEnum = ValidationResultEnum.Invalid,
                    ValidationResultMessageEnum = ValidationResultMessageEnum.NullProperty
                };`

Comment: The rest will have `ValidationResultEnum.Valid` and `ValidationResultMessageEnum.NotNullFound`

Comment: yes I got really close to my answer thanks, but here is my test result for second and third tests: Xunit.Sdk.EqualException
Assert.Equal() Failure
Expected: ValidationResult { ValidationResultEnum = Valid, ValidationResultMessageEnum = NotNullFound }
Actual:   ValidationResult { ValidationResultEnum = Valid, ValidationResultMessageEnum = NotNullFound }